# Two-dimensional ordering issue – alternate sort order ascending/descending to reduce fluctuations - trivial?

Tags: reference-request, sorting

I have a solution in search of a problem that some of you could perhaps help me with.

Let $L$ be a list of elements. Each element has two inherent properties/attributes ($a$, $b$) that can each be expressed as real numbers. The values of the two attributes of each element are completely uncorrelated. The goal is to re-order list $L$, such that for successive elements in the list, the differences in values of both attributes $a$ and $b$ are kept relatively small – i.e. we want to avoid big jumps in values from one element to the next.

Now, we could minimize fluctuations in attribute a by sorting the list by attribute $a$. However, since $a$ and $b$ are uncorrelated, the values for $b$ will then fluctuate randomly between minimum and maximum. If we instead sort by $b$, then $a$ is all over the place.

Instead, we opt to create a number of groups/bins based on attribute $a$, arrange those bins in order, and then order the elements within these bins by attribute $b$. This way, fluctuations in attribute $a$ can be no larger than two times the range of the bins (worst case: when traversing from one bin into the next), and no larger than one time the range of the bins when traversing within a bin. Fluctuations in attribute $b$ are also relatively small, as within the bins the values are sorted by $b$. The result looks something like this (attribute $a$ in blue, $b$ in orange):

[image]

A remaining issue then is that, when traversing from one bin into the next, there remains a big fluctuation in attribute $b$ – from approximately its maximum value to approximately its minimum (the “sawtooth wave” above). To improve on that, we alternate the sorting order between subsequent bins, to create a sort of “triangle wave”. This ensures that fluctuations in attribute b are small everywhere in the list:

[image]

I would like to ascertain how trivial it is for an engineer to come up with this ordering strategy – particularly the sorting within bins in an alternating fashion – if the objective is to reduce/minimize fluctuations in $a$ and $b$. To that end, I am looking for problems or applications (or perhaps an entire discipline?) where one is likely to encounter this ordering strategy.

While I have found an occasional post about someone trying to *implement* this particular order (e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88710/alternating-sort-order-within-a-sorted-group), it has proven surprisingly difficult to find any concrete examples showing *why* one would want to do this.

Does anything come to mind? Ultimately I aim to find (text)books showing this kind of problem and solution. Anything in that direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any references to offer, but your approach certainly makes some sort of sense to practitioners of algorithm design.

The solution is easier to understand if you realize that you can arrange your pairs $(a,b)$ as points in a two-dimensional place. Your "bins" are then simply vertical strips where you go through the points in one strip bottom up and then in the next strip top down; then repeat with the next two sets of strips.

Once you have made that leap, you will realize that this probably isn't the best strategy: It depends on the width of the strip, and if you had points that alternate between the left and right edges of a strip, then this kind of ordering is not going to be optimal. But there are well-understood solutions to these kinds of problems: Specifically, a better strategy would be to introduce a "space-filling curve" and order points based on their location on the space filling curve.

Answer (score 0):

Pursuant to Wolfgang's suggestions above, I have found the solution described above in a 1994 monograph from [Gerhard Reinelt, The Traveling Salesman (Berlin: Springer 1994)](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48661-5). It is called the "strip"-heuristic and can be used as a cheap way to find reasonable solutions to large traveling salesman problems.

Reinelt describes the strip heuristic as follows: "*The problem area is cut into vertical strips. Then a tour is constructed as follows. We start at the point in the first strip with lowest vertical coordinate, proceed to the node of strip 1 with next higher vertical coordinate, etc., until all points of the first strip are collected. The point with highest vertical coordinate in strip 1 is then connected to the node with highest vertical coordinate in strip 2, and strip 2 is scanned downwards. All remaining strips are then scanned connecting the points in the obvious way. Connecting the final point to the first point yields a Hamiltonian tour.*"

The strips described in Reinelt are equivalent to the bins in my original problem statement. The traversing of strip 1 upward, and then strip 2 downward, is equivalent to the alternating sorting order.

Comment: Could you expand your answer explaining some of the details of the method?